# CrawlSpider not executing callback

Tags: web-crawler, scrapy

I have created a spider by extending CrawlSpider.

When spider runs and finds article page I want to get a link to authors profile and make a request to the profile page and parse it with parse_author but for some reason, this parse_author callback is never executed.

My code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.http.request import Request


class CityamSpider4(CrawlSpider):

    name = "city_am_v4"
    custom_settings = {
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': '1',
    }
    allowed_domains = ['cityam.com']
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.cityam.com',
    ]
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(deny=('dev2.cityam.com', 'sponsored-content', )), callback='parse_item'),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        # parse article page
        article_title = response.css('.article-headline h1::text').extract_first(default='null').strip()
        if article_title is not 'null':
            print 'Article url : ' + response.url
            author_url = response.css('.author-container .author-text a.author-name::attr(href)').extract_first(default='null').strip()
            print 'Author link: ' + author_url
            author_url = response.urljoin(author_url)
            print 'Author link: ' + author_url
            yield Request(author_url, callback=self.parse_author)

    def parse_author(self, response):
        # parse author page
        author_name = response.css(".cam-profile-header-title::text").extract_first(default='null').strip()
        print 'Author name: ' + author_name
        yield {
            'name': author_name,
        }
```

Comment: It seems to me that python versions do not roll back over time, who uses version 2?

Comment: Only Gallaecio. Maybe he is right. Back to python 2 and you will be happy

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your link extraction rules also match author links, and Scrapy drops duplicate requests by default, so your `parse_item` method is the one receiving the responses that you expect in `parse_author`.

Possible solutions include:

- Modify your `LinkExtractor` not to match author URLs.
- Move your author-parsing logic from `parse_author` to `parse_item`.
- Add `dont_filter=True` to `Request` so that those requests that you are yielding are not filtered out even if they are duplicates of requests found by your link extractor.

Answer (score -1):

You are using the wrong port on the site pages:

1. HTTP: 80 port - **NOT**
2. HTTPS: 443 port - **YES**

Your line `yield Request(url=author_url, callback=self.parse_author)` refers to (for example) **http**://www.cityam.com/profile/joseph.ray (on port 80).

You must use the request via HTTPS: **https**://www.cityam.com/profile/joseph.ray
And then program execution will proceed to the method **parse_author**.

Change your request URL and everyone will be happy.
[image]
And by the way, I consider it a bad practice to write code like this:

`print 'Article url : ' + response.url` (Some compilers will not understand this and there will be an error.)

**Must be:** `print("Article url : " + response.url)`

Comment: This is great I wasted 3 days training to figure out this :) Can you clarify why i need to use https port even if the site is accessible via http port? Thanks again.

Comment: I just scanned it with online scanner for all possible ports. And it is not difficult to guess that this site will use https, since the information should be protected.

Comment: Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
80/tcp  open  http
443/tcp open  https
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 10.24 seconds

Comment: As you might have guessed, a key factor in using HTTPS is security. It maximally prevents the theft of your data on the way from your device to the server.

Comment: This is not the issue. And the comment about `print` is out of place, the user code is clearly Python 2 and those print statements are perfectly fine in Python 2.